# Unable to catch exception in opening a shapefile geotoools

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I am loading a shapefile where .shx file is missing I am getting the following error. I am unable to catch this exception please help me.

error log:

> Could not open the .shx file, continuing assuming the .shp file is not
>   sparse java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\shapes\123.shx (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)   at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:216)    at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShpFiles.getReadChannel(ShpFiles.java:831)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile.(IndexFile.java:79)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.(ShapefileReader.java:268)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.(ShapefileReader.java:240)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.openShapeReader(ShapefileDataStore.java:599)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.readAttributes(ShapefileDataStore.java:826)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.getSchema(ShapefileDataStore.java:784)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.AbstractFileDataStore.getFeatureSource(AbstractFileDataStore.java:77)

code:

```
public boolean openShapeFile() throws Exception {
     File dataFile = new File(fileName);
     dataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(dataFile.toURL());
     SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource();
     final SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = source.getFeatures();
     shapeFeatureIterator = featureCollection.features();
     return true;
 }
 try {
     openShapeFile();
 } catch (Exception exep) {
     return false;
 }
```

complete code

```
public class test 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        try
        {
            File dataFile = new File("D:\\shapes\\123.shp");
            ShapefileDataStore dataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(dataFile.toURL());
            SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource();
            final SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = source.getFeatures();
            SimpleFeatureIterator shapeFeatureIterator = featureCollection.features();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this code after deleting the 123.shx file but I was not able to catch the above exception because the control not at all coming to catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's better to use the return type you've declared rather than rely on exceptions, so something like this may work better:

```
public boolean openShapeFile() {
    try {
        File dataFile = new File(fileName);
        dataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(dataFile.toURL());
        SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource();
        final SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = source.getFeatures();
        shapeFeatureIterator = featureCollection.features();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello sir here control is not coming to catch block but error is getting displayed on the console in my case (.shx file not exist on shapepath). In catch block i need to display a message (Incorrect shapefile ...etc)  to the user  without printing error message on console.

Comment: I think in that case it is a warning and you can continue to use the shapefile. Do you have features in the iterator?

Comment: yes i have a polygon features

Comment: then there is no problem